# Code not working when I add setOnItemClickLIstener bit to it

Tags: android, android-studio

My other part of my code is working fine but then when I add the setOnItemClickListener part in this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView people = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.peopleList);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(PeepList.size() != 0)
        UpdateList();
    people.setClickable(true);
    people.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(pos == 0){

            }
            if(pos == 1){
                PeepList.remove(position);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

it tells me my app has stopped running as soon as I try to emulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change few line,you init `people` listview before `setContentView` so your listview is `null` and you try to set `onClick` for null object change it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ListView people = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.peopleList);
if(PeepList.size() != 0)
    UpdateList();
people.setClickable(true);
people.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(pos == 0){

        }
        if(pos == 1){
            PeepList.remove(position);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setContentView should be set before findView By Id.Inerchange T